# quitar cuadro azul al hacer clic en icono o imagen tipo boton

Tags: html, css

saludos cuando hago clic en una imagen tipo boton desde un dispositivo movil sale este cuadro azul

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como haria para que no saliera o por lo menos que pueda cambiarle el color?

Comment: Será difícil ayudarte si no comparte si no colocas el código. Lee [mcve] y luego puedes [edit] la pregunta

Comment: Si, lo que pasa es que no se donde podria ubicarse esta configuracion, tal vez tenga un nombre para ver si lo puedo conseguir en el archivo css?

Comment: Si usas chrome, puedes darle clic derecho y luego inspeccionar elemento, debe salir alguna id o class para que busques en el css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba en el CSS

```
a { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
```

Comment: Saludos si me sirvio, excelente pero hay unas partes donde no funciona me refiero que hay botones donde aun sigue saliendo azul

Comment: Como te mencionaban, es necesario que veamos el código (html y css) de esos 'botones' para ver que tipo de elemento son,. El otro código que te sugieren en la otra respuesta complementa el que te di yo. ¿Ya probaste agregarlo también?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a añadir esto al css:

```
textarea, select, input, button { 
    outline: none;
}
:focus { 
    outline-color: transparent; 
    outline-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Ya lo intente pero no sirvio, trate de eliminar todo y probarlo solo con un boton sin codigo css ni nada y parece que es una propiedad automatica en el navegador movil al hacer clic a un boton pero he visto paginas donde al hacer clic el recuadro azul no sale como hacen ellos?

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

La respuesta original con el a, solo te aplicará a los elementos "a". La tercera respuesta donde te dicen aplicar el atributo a todo, lo que debes colocar es un asterisco para que ese atributo css se aplique a todo. A mi me funcionó con todos los elementos a los que les hago click y me aparecía el fondo azul que comentas.

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score -1):

Yo le puse para todos y me funciono ..

```
{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Hola Pedro, bienvenido. ¿no es lo mismo que la respuesta ya aceptada?

Comment: @Pollo. La única diferencia es la  'a' al principio. ¿Será relevante?

Comment: deberias explicar mejor en que se diferencia esto de la respuesta aceptada...